# Neural network: nb of photos going through the epochs + dealing with input sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I found an algorithm online, and I'm trying to adapt it.
However, the algorithm I found deals with `(28,28,1)` inputs. I need to deal with `(256,256,3)` inputs. I changed the input size in the first layer, but I don't know whether or not I have to change other parameters as well.

I have another question: when I run my algorithm, only 44 photos seem to be going through the epochs, even though 2700 are supposed to. I'd like to know why that is.

```
rock_model = Sequential()
rock_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),activation='linear',input_shape=(256,256,3),padding='same'))
rock_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
rock_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2),padding='same'))
rock_model.add(Dropout(0.25))
rock_model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
rock_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
rock_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
rock_model.add(Dropout(0.25))
rock_model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='linear',padding='same'))
rock_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))                  
rock_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
rock_model.add(Dropout(0.4))
rock_model.add(Flatten())
rock_model.add(Dense(128, activation='linear'))
rock_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))        
rock_model.add(Dropout(0.3))          
rock_model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: *only 44 photos seem to be going through the epochs*, I think you confuse steps per epoch with total images.

Comment: Can you share the minimal code (if it can be shared) to reproduce the issue?